# How do I parse a string into a number with Dart?

Tags: string, parsing, dart

I would like to parse strings like `1` or `32.23` into integers and doubles. How can I do this with Dart?

Comment: apart from below answers if your string has letters you can do like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61401948/614026

Answer (score 445, accepted):

You can parse a string into an integer with `int.parse()`. For example:

```dart
var myInt = int.parse('12345');
assert(myInt is int);
print(myInt); // 12345
```

Note that `int.parse()` accepts `0x` prefixed strings. Otherwise the input is treated as base-10.

You can parse a string into a double with `double.parse()`. For example:

```dart
var myDouble = double.parse('123.45');
assert(myDouble is double);
print(myDouble); // 123.45
```

`parse()` will throw FormatException if it cannot parse the input.

Comment: How should you parse an integer from a string that contains invalid characters later on? E.g., "-01:00", where I want to get -1, or "172 apples" where I would expect to get 172. In JavaScript parseInt("-01:00") works just fine but Dart gives an error. Is there any easy way without checking manually character-by-character? Thanks.

Answer (score 155):

In Dart 2 [int.tryParse](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.53.0/dart-core/int/tryParse.html) is available.

It returns null for invalid inputs instead of throwing. You can use it like this:

```
int val = int.tryParse(text) ?? defaultValue;
```

Comment: This is not working fpr number with texts ex: "323pm32"

Answer (score 65):

#### Convert String to Int

```dart
var myInt = int.parse('12345');
assert(myInt is int);
print(myInt); // 12345
print(myInt.runtimeType);
```

#### Convert String to Double

```dart
var myDouble = double.parse('123.45');
assert(myInt is double);
print(myDouble); // 123.45
print(myDouble.runtimeType);
```

#### [Example in DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/5bddb5fb077c3f0e63db88c33fdbb1f1?)

[image: screenshot of dartpad]

Answer (score 17):

**As per dart 2.6**

The optional `onError` parameter of `int.parse` is **deprecated**. Therefore, you should use `int.tryParse` instead.

**Note**:
The same applies to `double.parse`. Therefore, use `double.tryParse` instead.

```
  /**
   * ...
   *
   * The [onError] parameter is deprecated and will be removed.
   * Instead of `int.parse(string, onError: (string) => ...)`,
   * you should use `int.tryParse(string) ?? (...)`.
   *
   * ...
   */
  external static int parse(String source, {int radix, @deprecated int onError(String source)});
```

The difference is that `int.tryParse` returns `null` if the source string is invalid.

```
  /**
   * Parse [source] as a, possibly signed, integer literal and return its value.
   *
   * Like [parse] except that this function returns `null` where a
   * similar call to [parse] would throw a [FormatException],
   * and the [source] must still not be `null`.
   */
  external static int tryParse(String source, {int radix});
```

So, in your case it should look like:

```
// Valid source value
int parsedValue1 = int.tryParse('12345');
print(parsedValue1); // 12345

// Error handling
int parsedValue2 = int.tryParse('');
if (parsedValue2 == null) {
  print(parsedValue2); // null
  //
  // handle the error here ...
  //
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is helpful & upvote.  `tryParse` should be used to check null :D

Answer (score 16):

```
 void main(){
  var x = "4";
  int number = int.parse(x);//STRING to INT

  var y = "4.6";
  double doubleNum = double.parse(y);//STRING to DOUBLE

  var z = 55;
  String myStr = z.toString();//INT to STRING
}
```

> int.parse() and double.parse() can throw an error when it couldn't parse the String

Comment: `int.parse()` and `double.parse()` can throw an error when it couldn't parse the String. Please elaborate on your answer so that others can learn and understand dart better.

Comment: Thank-you for mentioning it josxha, I am an absolute beginner in Dart and I'm trying my best to help others, Well I thought it would be the simplest answer, anyway Thanks!!

Answer (score 13):

Above solutions will not work for `String` like:

```
String str = '123 km';
```

So, the answer in a single line, that works in every situation for me will be:

```
int r = int.tryParse(str.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), '')) ?? defaultValue;
or
int? r = int.tryParse(str.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), ''));
```

But be warned that it will not work for the below kind of string

```
String problemString = 'I am a fraction 123.45';
String moreProblem = '20 and 30 is friend';
```

If you want to extract double which will work in every kind then use:

```
double d = double.tryParse(str.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9\.]'), '')) ?? defaultValue;
or
double? d = double.tryParse(str.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9\.]'), ''));
```

This will work for `problemString` but not for `moreProblem`.

Comment: This is the answer. THank you

Answer (score 8):

you can parse string with `int.parse('your string value');`.

Example:- `int num = int.parse('110011'); print(num); // prints 110011 ;`

Answer (score 7):

```
void main(){
String myString ='111';
int data = int.parse(myString);
print(data);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know whether your type is string or int you can do like this:

```
int parseInt(dynamic s){
  if(s.runtimeType==String) return int.parse(s);
  return s as int;
}
```

For double:

```
double parseDouble(dynamic s){
  if(s.runtimeType==String) return double.parse(s);
  return s as double;
}
```

Therefore you can do parseInt('1') or parseInt(1)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for easy conversion like this

[Example Code Here](https://dartpad.dev/?)

```
void main() {
  var myInt = int.parse('12345');
 var number = myInt.toInt();
  print(number); // 12345
  print(number.runtimeType);  // int
  
  
    var myDouble = double.parse('123.45');
  var double_int = myDouble.toDouble();
  print(double_int); // 123.45
   print(double_int.runtimeType);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String age = stdin.readLineSync()!; // first take the input from user in string form
int.parse(age);  // then parse it to integer that's it
```

Answer (score 0):

for easy reading, you can make it an extension

```dart
extension MyCustomString on String {
  double? get strToDouble {
    double? d = double.tryParse(replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9\.]'), ''));
    return d;
  }
  
  int? get strToInt {
    int? i = int.tryParse(replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), ''));
    return i;
  }
}

void main() {
  var myString = '13.2';
  var myDouble = myString.strToDouble;
  print(myDouble);
  print(myDouble.runtimeType);
  
  myString = '13';
  var myInt = myString.strToInt;
  print(myInt);
  print(myInt.runtimeType);
}
```

https://dartpad.dev/49bde0c1ed780decc902f3d4d06d8f0c?

Answer (score 0):

If the default value is 0 you can use something like `double.parse("0${textfieldController.value.text}");` adding a zero before the string you are trying to parse ensuring that no exceptions are raised even when the input is empty or cannot be successfully converted into a numeric value.