# How do I avoid using 'as' when casting from double to int?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to calculate a percentage value as follows where `count` and `size` are integers:

```
var percent = count * 100 / size as int;
```

But I get a warning that says, "avoid using as". I want to percent to be an integer type.  How can I rewrite this to avoid using 'as'?

Comment: I don't know about Dart but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167496/how-do-i-parse-a-string-into-a-number-with-dart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the truncating division operator [`~/`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html) to do what you want.

```
var percent = count * 100 ~/ size;
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoops, turns out I cannot use 'as int' because int is not a subclass of double.  Instead I need to use the round() method which returns an int like this:

```
    var percent = (count * 100 / size).round();
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition of Alexandre Ardhuin's answer:

As far as I know, dart isn't that flexible with casting and therefore it's not advised (not even allowed in this case).

You can use a round() function instead:

```
int count = 1;
int size = 3;
var percent = (count * 100 / size);
print(percent);

int asInt = percent.round();
print(asInt);
```

or if you want typical `interger rounding`, use [floor()](https://api.dartlang.org/be/158658/dart-core/num/floor.html):

```
int count = 1;
int size = 3;
var percent = (count * 100 / size);
print(percent);

int asInt = percent.floor();
print(asInt);
```

*Note:* in these examples, percent is a double and can be stored for later use.

---

For completeness, including `ceil`:

```
int count = 2;
int size = 3;

var percent = (count * 100 / size);
print(percent);

int asIntRound = percent.round();
print(asIntRound);

int asIntFloor = percent.floor();
print(asIntFloor);

int asIntCeil = percent.ceil();
print(asIntCeil);
```

Output:

```
66.66666666666667
67
66
67
```