# Dart: convert a string to int, and to compare 2 integers

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to convert a string to int and to compare 2 ints :

**I tried :**

```
  var str1="0.0.1";
  var str2="0.0.2";

  var s1 = int.parse(str1.replaceAll(".", ""));
  var s2 = int.parse(str2.replaceAll(".", ""));

  print(s1); //1
  print(s2); //2

  if(s1 < s2){
    print("ok");
  }
```

but I get:

[image]

any idea?

[image]

Comment: `int.parse(str)` returns `3`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated the question with the error message, any idea?

Comment: You removed the part about what value `str1` or `str2` were when you got the error.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I added str1 in the question, it fails when I add the comparison, strange.. any idea?

Comment: Prints `Restarted application in 3,989ms.
I/flutter (16587): 1
I/flutter (16587): 2
I/flutter (16587): ok` for me.

Comment: What Flutter version are you using?

Comment: Your Flutter version is quite outdated.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  Dart 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

Comment: Try `flutter channel dev` `flutter doctor` and then try again.

Comment: still the error message, but my dart version is now  Dart 2.1.1 (build 2.1.1-dev.3.2 f4afaee422)

Comment: Just works for me. No idea what's going on.

Comment: Strange. I've tried it on [dart try it](https://dart.dev/#try-dart) page. `print(s1);` and I got "1", same with  `print(s2);` printed "2". Comparing `s1` and `s2`, the output is "ok". Could you run `flutter doctor -v` and show us the result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string into a number with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167496/how-do-i-parse-a-string-into-a-number-with-dart)

Answer (score 0):

The code runs without issues on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) with Flutter 2.2.1 and Dart SDK 2.13.1. It prints the following

```
1
2
ok
```

`int._throwFormatException` is usually displayed when the source String is invalid as mentioned on the [SDK](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/core/int.dart). I also suggest trying to update the Flutter and Dart SDK that you're using to see if it fixes the issue on your end.