# How to extract number only from string in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Lets say that I have a string:

```
a="23questions";
b="2questions3";
```

Now I need to parse 23 from both string. How do I extract that number or any number from a string value?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The following code can extract the number:

```
aStr = a.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^0-9]'),''); // '23'
```

You can parse it into integer using:

```
aInt = int.parse(aStr);
```

Comment: Single Line version:  `int intValue = int.parse(myString.replaceAll(RegExp('[^0-9]'), ''));`

Answer (score 12):

```
const text = "23questions";
```

Step 1: Find matches using regex:

```
final intInStr = RegExp(r'\d+');
```

Step 2: Do whatever you want with the result:

```
void main() {
  print(intInStr.allMatches(text).map((m) => m.group(0)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but I feel like above solution will suffice and would be cleaner.