# Flutter - convert string to int without losing leading zero

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to convert the clock time (e.g., '05:34') to integer without losing the leading zero (e.g., 0534).

Currently I can convert it to int but it results in (534). I use this code (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61401948)):

```
int tmpInt = int.parse(tmpString.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), ''));
```

**EDIT**: I need to do this as these values will be sent as raw integers to another dump device to display the time.

Comment: You should never store the time as int using this format. Instead use a class dedicated to this use case

Comment: Still impossible

Comment: You can't do what you want because an integer is an integer and never starts with 0.
You'll have to find another solution ;)

Comment: Ok. This makes sense :) . Thanks for your fast replies

Comment: you can create some variable to count leading 0, but better to have string after conversation, it will be `"0534"` string type